# yii2 CRUD ActiveForm does not send id to Update action

Tags: yii2

I am trying to update data but when i click on the submit button all i get is `Bad request (#400) missing required parameter: id`. It was working on the previous project and all the files are created by `Gii CRUD`. I have the same issue when i am trying to `create` data but guess i am making same mistake with it. What is wrong? What i am doing wrong?Thank you in advance!
View:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'update-form'
                ]); ?>
                <?php $languages = Lang::find()->all(); ?>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <?php
        foreach ($languages as $key => $language) {
            if ($language->default == 1) {
                echo '<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' . $key . '">' . $language->name . '</a></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' . $key . '">' . $language->name . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php
        foreach ($languages as $key => $language) {
            if ($language->default != 1) {
                echo '<div id="' . $key . '" class="tab-pane fade">';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'title_' . $language->url)->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'url_' . $language->url)->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'meta_title_' . $language->url)->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'meta_description_' . $language->url)->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div col-xs-12><div class="form-group">';
                $textContent = 'content_' . $language->url;
                if (!$model->isNewRecord) {
                    $model->$textContent = OutData::showTXT($model->$textContent);
                }
                echo $form->field($model, 'content_' . $language->url)->textarea();
                echo "<script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'Page[content_$language->url]' );
                    </script>";
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div id="' . $key . '" class="tab-pane fade in active">';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'title')->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'url')->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'meta_title')->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'meta_description')->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="form-group">';
                if (!$model->isNewRecord) {
                    $model->content = OutData::showTXT($model->content);
                }
                echo $form->field($model, 'content')->textarea();
                echo "<script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'Page[content]' );
                    </script>";
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php
            $mas[0] = Yii::t('app', 'Главна страница');
            $mas['----------------'] = ArrayHelper::map(Page::find()->where('id_in=0 and is_cat=1')->all(), 'id', 'title');
            ?>
            <?=
            $form->field($model, 'id_in')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'id_in',
                'data' => $mas,
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select a type ...'),
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ])
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php
            if ($model->isNewRecord) {
                echo $form->field($model, 'view_id')->hiddenInput(['value' => 12])->label(false);
            } else {
                echo $form->field($model, 'view_id')->hiddenInput(['value' => $model->view_id])->label(false);
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'sort')->textInput() ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'active')->hiddenInput(['value' => ($model->active) ? $model->active : 2])->label(false) ?>

            <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'active', ['class' => 'dblock flLeft mr5 pt5']); ?>
            <label class="switch switch-custom block dblock flLeft">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="active_<?= $model->id ?>"class="legend-switch" <?= ($model->active == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> onchange="changeHiddenField('page-active', 'active_<?= $model->id ?>');"></input>
                <label data-off="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Не'); ?>" data-on="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Да') ?>" for="active_<?= $model->id ?>"></label>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'in_main_menu')->hiddenInput(['value' => ($model->in_main_menu) ? $model->in_main_menu : 2])->label(false) ?>

            <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'in_main_menu', ['class' => 'dblock flLeft mr5 pt5']); ?>
            <label class="switch switch-custom block dblock flLeft">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="in_main_menu_<?= $model->id ?>"class="legend-switch" <?= ($model->in_main_menu == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> onchange="changeHiddenField('page-in_main_menu', 'in_main_menu_<?= $model->id ?>');"></input>
                <label data-off="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Не'); ?>" data-on="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Да') ?>" for="in_main_menu_<?= $model->id ?>"></label>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'in_side_menu')->hiddenInput(['value' => ($model->in_side_menu) ? $model->in_side_menu : 2])->label(false) ?>

            <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'in_side_menu', ['class' => 'dblock flLeft mr5 pt5']); ?>
            <label class="switch switch-custom block dblock flLeft">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="in_side_menu_<?= $model->id ?>"class="legend-switch" <?= ($model->in_side_menu == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> onchange="changeHiddenField('page-in_side_menu', 'in_side_menu_<?= $model->id ?>');"></input>
                <label data-off="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Не'); ?>" data-on="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Да') ?>" for="in_side_menu_<?= $model->id ?>"></label>
            </label>
        </div>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'is_cat')->hiddenInput(['value' => ($model->is_cat) ? $model->is_cat : 0])->label(false) ?>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'app.Create') : Yii::t('app', 'app.Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id, true);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $model = $this->findModel($model->id, true);
            $languages = Lang::find()->all();
            foreach ($languages as $language) {
                if ($language->default != 1) {
                    $title = 'title_' . $language->url;
                    // $url = MakeURL::parseUrl($model->$title, $model->id);
                    $urlName = 'url_' . $language->url;
                    if($model->old_link == 1){
                        $model->$urlName = MakeURL::parseUrl($model->$urlName, $model->id);
                    }else{
                        $model->$urlName = MakeURL::parseUrlGoogle($model->$urlName, $model->id);
                    }
                    $content = 'content_' . $language->url;
                    $var =  Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->$content);
                    $model->$content = $var;
                } else {
                    // $url1 = MakeURL::parseUrl($model->title, $model->id);
                    if($model->old_link == 1){
                        $model->url = MakeURL::parseUrl($model->url, $model->id);
                    }else{
                        $model->url = MakeURL::parseUrlGoogle($model->url, $model->id);
                    }
                    $model->content = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->content);
                }
            }
            $model->dt_update = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $model->update_user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $model->save();
            //return $this->redirect(['index']);
            return $this->redirect([Yii::$app->session['ReturnUrl']]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
```

This action expects a required parameter `$id` when it's called but you're not passing it (it goes something like `index.php?r=site/update` but it should be like this: `index.php?r=site/update&id=10`). Solution to that problem is to add the following line to `ActiveForm` parameters:

```
'action' => Url::to(['site/update', 'id' => $id]),
```

Where `$id` is the ID of the model. And this makes:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'update-form',
    'action' => Url::to(['site/update', 'id' => $id]),
]); ?>
```

*Sorry in advance if this is defined somewhere else, I haven't look at a whole code.*